# Pandas: creating a lagged column with grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lag

I'm working with the following `DataFrame`:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/crsp.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(url)

df.head()

    feccandid   fec.dyn feccf   cid     date_crsp   catcode     amtsum
0   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005    J2100        2.1
1   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005    L1200        5.0
2   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005    J7300        0.0
4   S8NM00127   0.561   0.382   N00015616   2006    G2900        2.5
5   S8NJ00350   -0.329  NaN     N00000854   2005    LG000        7.5
```

I would like to lag the `amtsum`values by year. The following code shows how I derived `amtsum`and provides insight into the nature of my desired outcome:

```
crsp['amtsum']=crsp[['date_crsp', 'cid', 'catcode', 'amount']].\
groupby(['date_crsp', 'catcode','cid']).amount.transform('sum')
crsp['amtsum'] = crsp['amtsum'] / 1000
crsp.drop(['amount'], axis=1, inplace=True)
crsp.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, keep='first')
```

I have tried using the following code to get lagged values:

```
crsp['amtsumlag.1']=crsp.groupby(['date_crsp','catcode', 'cid'])['amtsum'].shift(1)
```

This returns

```
    feccandid   fec.dyn     feccf   cid     date_crsp   catcode     amtsum  amtsumlag.1
0   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005       J2100    2.1     NaN
1   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005       L1200    5.0     NaN
2   S8VT00018   NaN     NaN     N00000534   2005       J7300    0.0     NaN
4   S8NM00127   0.561   0.382   N00015616   2006       G2900    2.5     NaN
5   S8NJ00350   -0.329  NaN     N00000854   2005       LG000    7.5     NaN
```

Since my `date_crsp`range is from 2005 to 2014 I expect to have `NaN`for 2005 but not for 2006. I have also selected only dates after 2005 and got the same results. Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into your `.groupby()` logic.

```
crsp.groupby(['date_crsp','catcode', 'cid']).size().value_counts()
```

results in

```
1    444508
2      5281
3       619
4         3
```

Most of the groups have only a single value, so there's not much to shift. Unsurprisingly,

```
crsp['amtsumlag.1'] = crsp.groupby(['catcode', 'cid', 'date_crsp'])['amtsum'].shift(1)
```

results in:

```
Data columns (total 8 columns):
feccandid             456939 non-null object
feccandcfscore.dyn    445710 non-null float64
feccandcfscore        355887 non-null float64
cid                   456939 non-null object
date_crsp             456939 non-null int64
catcode               456939 non-null object
amtsum                456939 non-null float64
amtsumlag.1           6528 non-null float64
```

If you want to `.shift()` by `date_crsp`, for instance, you probably do not want to use it in `.groupby()` - each group would then only contain a single year. One would expect to see unique group `id` variables in `.groupby()`, and ideally a `DateTimeIndex`, or otherwise a sorted `DataFrame`. So `.sort_values('date_crsp')` might be a good idea.

```
crsp['amtsumlag.1'] = crsp.sort_values('date_crsp').groupby(['catcode', 'cid'])['amtsum'].shift(1)
```

instead yields:

```
feccandid             456939 non-null object
feccandcfscore.dyn    445710 non-null float64
feccandcfscore        355887 non-null float64
cid                   456939 non-null object
date_crsp             456939 non-null int64
catcode               456939 non-null object
amtsum                456939 non-null float64
amtsumlag.1           301280 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(1), object(3)
```

Without know the data enough to understand what identifies the groups you are trying to lag it's hard to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion. I recognize that not having a unique index is one problem. Unfortunately, it is not a very 'normal' data frame. I'm messing around with some different ideas, i.e. creating a `date_crsp_lag` based off of `date_crsp` to see if something like that might work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to shift the years by one, prepare a new column of years:

```
crsp['next_year'] = crsp['date_crsp'] + 1
```

and then groupby by `['next_year', 'catcode', 'cid']` instead of `['date_crsp', 'catcode', 'cid']`:

```
crsp['amtsumlag.1'] = (crsp.groupby(['next_year', 'catcode', 'cid'])['amount']
                       .transform('sum'))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, this is a smart solution which suits for different situations.